# Problems with CSS nav-bar

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a nav-bar using HTML and CSS. However, the nav-Bar doesn't stretch to the end of the page like I would like it to. I have tried using `padding-left-: 0px` and `padding-right: 0px;` however this does not work.

Here is my work so far:

```css
$banner-height: 50px;
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:400,500,900';

nav {
  height: $banner-height * 2;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  transition: top 0.2s ease-out;
}

.banner {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: $banner-height;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #FEFFB7;
  box-shadow: inset 0px -1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.13);
}

.nav-bar {
  top: $banner-height;
  /* Rectangle 1: */
  background: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.11), 0px 4px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.11);
  width: 100%;
  line-height: $banner-height;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-up {
  top: -$banner-height;
}

 //-------------------------------------------------------
 /*Strip the ul of padding and list styling*/
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    
    position: absolute;
}
/*Create a horizontal list with spacing*/
li {
    display:inline-block;
    float: center;
    margin-right: 1px;
}
/*Style for menu links*/
li a {
    display:block;
    min-width:140px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    background: #2f3036;
    text-decoration: none;
}
/*Hover state for top level links*/
li:hover a {
    background: #19c589;
}
/*Style for dropdown links*/
li:hover ul a {
    background: #f3f3f3;
    color: #2f3036;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
}
/*Hover state for dropdown links*/
li:hover ul a:hover {
    background: #19c589;
    color: #fff;
}
/*Hide dropdown links until they are needed*/
li ul {
    display: none;
}
/*Make dropdown links vertical*/
li ul li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
}
/*Prevent text wrapping*/
li ul li a {
    width: auto;
    min-width: 100px;
    padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
}
/*Display the dropdown on hover*/
ul li a:hover + .hidden, .hidden:hover {
    display: block;
}
/*Style 'show menu' label button and hide it by default*/
.show-menu {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #19c589;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
    display: none;
}
/*Hide checkbox*/
input[type=checkbox]{
    display: none;
}
/*Show menu when invisible checkbox is checked*/
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #menu{
    display: block;
}
/*Responsive Styles*/
@media screen and (max-width : 760px){
    /*Make dropdown links appear inline*/
    ul {
        position: static;
        display: none;
 
    }
    /*Create vertical spacing*/
    li {
        margin-bottom: 1px;
    }
    /*Make all menu links full width*/
    ul li, li a {
        width: 100%;
    }
    /*Display 'show menu' link*/
    .show-menu {
        display:block;
    }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

</head>

<body>

<nav class="nav-down">
  <div class="banner animated">I'm a banner</div>
  <div class="nav-bar">    <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Show Menu</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">
        <ul id="menu" >
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li>
   <a href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
   <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul></div>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem:

[image]

[image]

(View in full screen to see the full problem).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updated: Solution in snippet, flexbox and paddding left for the UL set to 0.

Seeing some inconsistent behavior with the embedded snippet, so here is a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/2u1kzy3c/

```css
$banner-height: 50px;
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:400,500,900';

nav {
  height: $banner-height * 2;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  transition: top 0.2s ease-out;
}

.banner {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: $banner-height;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #FEFFB7;
  box-shadow: inset 0px -1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.13);
}

nav ul#menu {
    padding-left: 0;
    display: flex;
}

nav ul li {
   flex-grow: 1;
   }

.nav-bar {
  top: $banner-height;
  /* Rectangle 1: */
  background: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.11), 0px 4px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.11);
  width: 100%;
  line-height: $banner-height;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-up {
  top: -$banner-height;
}

 //-------------------------------------------------------
 /*Strip the ul of padding and list styling*/
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    
    position: absolute;
}
/*Create a horizontal list with spacing*/
li {
    display:inline-block;
    float: center;
    margin-right: 1px;
}
/*Style for menu links*/
li a {
    display:block;
    min-width:140px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    background: #2f3036;
    text-decoration: none;
}
/*Hover state for top level links*/
li:hover a {
    background: #19c589;
}
/*Style for dropdown links*/
li:hover ul a {
    background: #f3f3f3;
    color: #2f3036;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
}
/*Hover state for dropdown links*/
li:hover ul a:hover {
    background: #19c589;
    color: #fff;
}
/*Hide dropdown links until they are needed*/
li ul {
    display: none;
}
/*Make dropdown links vertical*/
li ul li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
}
/*Prevent text wrapping*/
li ul li a {
    width: auto;
    min-width: 100px;
    padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
}
/*Display the dropdown on hover*/
ul li a:hover + .hidden, .hidden:hover {
    display: block;
}
/*Style 'show menu' label button and hide it by default*/
.show-menu {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #19c589;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
    display: none;
}
/*Hide checkbox*/
input[type=checkbox]{
    display: none;
}
/*Show menu when invisible checkbox is checked*/
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #menu{
    display: block;
}
/*Responsive Styles*/
@media screen and (max-width : 760px){
    /*Make dropdown links appear inline*/
    nav ul#menu {
        position: static;
        display: none;
 
    }
    /*Create vertical spacing*/
    li {
        margin-bottom: 1px;
    }
    /*Make all menu links full width*/
    ul li, li a {
        width: 100%;
    }
    /*Display 'show menu' link*/
    .show-menu {
        display:block;
    }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

</head>

<body>

<nav class="nav-down">
  <div class="banner animated">I'm a banner</div>
  <div class="nav-bar">    <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Show Menu</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">
        <ul id="menu" >
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li>
   <a href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
   <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul></div>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'd use <code>.nav-bar ul</code> to avoid affecting ul outside of the navbar.

Comment: sorry but doesn't fix it when viewed in full screen

Comment: Use flexbox (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) instead, it's more flexible and can help you solve the probleme on every device.

Comment: sorry but still don't fix it when on full-screen

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by fix? Do  you want it to stretch to the bottom of the page? The solution I provided makes the nav bar stretch to the right and left of the screen, which is what I assumed you were trying to accomplish.

Comment: so when the nav bar is viewed in full screen I want it to stretch across the left to right of the page.

Comment: @Hamza It does! When I view the fullscreen layout all 5 links are stretched to fill the available space. What are you seeing?

Comment: There were some inconsistencies with the embedded snippet, so take a look at the linked jsfiddle if you are still not seeing it.

Comment: sorry the embedded snippet was showing me something different i 1+ and thank you for your time

Comment: could you 1+ please?